# Passing data to custom picker

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, picker

Currently I'm developing an app with a picker on it and I'm using picker component from react native but it doesn't work perfectly on iOS device so I found a custom picker using picker and modal it renders a modal on iOS only.
Here is the code

```js
class PickerWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            type_absen: '',
            modal: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        let picker;

        let iosPickerModal = (
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.modal} hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true} backdropColor={color.white} backdropOpacity={0.9} animationIn="zoomInDown" animationOut="zoomOutUp" animationInTiming={200} animationOutTiming={200} onBackButtonPress={() => this.setState({ modal: false })} onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ modal: false })} >
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: color.white, width: 0.9 * windowWidth(), height: 0.3 * windowHeight(), justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.type_absen}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ type_absen: itemValue });
                            this.setState({ modal: false });
                            setTimeout(() => this.props.onSelect(itemValue), 1200);
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.props.items.map((item, key) => <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key} />)}
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </Modal>);

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios')
            return (
                <View style={this.props.style}>
                    {iosPickerModal}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ modal: true })}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : normalize(40), width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : 0.68 * windowWidth(), borderWidth: 1, borderColor: color.blue, alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5 }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: fontSize.regular, marginRight: 30 }}> {this.state.type_absen}</Text>
                            <IconWrapper name='md-arrow-dropdown' type='ionicon' color={color.light_grey} size={20} onPress={() => this.setState({ modal: true })} style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 10 }} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View >);
        else
            return (
                <View style={this.props.style} >
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.type_absen}
                        style={{ height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : normalize(20), width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : normalize(150) }}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ type_absen: itemValue });
                            this.props.onSelect(itemValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.props.items.map((item, key) => <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key} />)}
                    </Picker>
                </View>);
    }
}

PickerWrapper.propTypes = {
    onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default PickerWrapper;
```

I successfully load the data from api, but I still confused on how to get the value from it, and here is my old code using picker component

```js
<Picker
 selectedValue={this.state.type_absen}
 style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
 onValueChange={(val) => this.setState({ type_absen: val })}> 
   {
   this.props.schedules ?   this.props.schedules.map((item, key) => { 
     return <Picker.Item value={item.id} label {item.description} key={item.id} />})
 :
  []
   } 
</Picker>
```

and this is my new code using the PickerWrapper

```js
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  token: state.authReducer.token,
  message: state.authReducer.message,
  schedules: state.authReducer.schedules
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actionsAuth: bindActionCreators(authAction, dispatch)
});

class Change extends Component {
    
  constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            type_absen: [],
        }
    }
    
    onPickerValueChange=(value, index)=>{
    this.setState({type_absen: value}, 
      () => {
        Alert.alert("type_absen", this.state.type_absen);
      }
    );
  }
  
  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}>             
                  <PickerWrapper items={this.props.schedules.map((item) => item.description )} onSelect={this.onPickerValueChange} />
                  
                </View>  
              </View>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
    
 }
```

what I'm trying to do is get the `item.id`. How do I do that in my PickerWrapper component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class component change the picker wrapper like this

```
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: state.authReducer.token,
    message: state.authReducer.message,
    schedules: state.authReducer.schedules
  });

  export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    actionsAuth: bindActionCreators(authAction, dispatch)
  });

  class Change extends Component {

    constructor(){
          super();
          this.state={
              type_absen: [],
          }
      }

      onPickerValueChange=(value, index)=>{
      this.setState({type_absen: value}, 
        () => {
          Alert.alert("type_absen", this.state.type_absen);
        }
      );
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                  <View style={styles.innerContainer}>             
                    <PickerWrapper items={this.props.schedules} onSelect={this.onPickerValueChange.bind(this)} />

                  </View>  
                </View>
          </View>
        );
    }
  }
```

and then in your PickerWrapper component change it to be like this

```
class PickerWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            type_absen: '',
            modal: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        let picker;

        let iosPickerModal = (
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.modal} hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true} backdropColor={color.white} backdropOpacity={0.9} animationIn="zoomInDown" animationOut="zoomOutUp" animationInTiming={200} animationOutTiming={200} onBackButtonPress={() => this.setState({ modal: false })} onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ modal: false })} >
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: color.white, width: 0.9 * windowWidth(), height: 0.3 * windowHeight(), justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.type_absen}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ type_absen: itemValue });
                            this.setState({ modal: false });
                            setTimeout(() => this.props.onSelect(itemValue), 1200);
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.props.items.map((item, key) => <Picker.Item label={item.description} value={item.id} key={key} />)}
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </Modal>);

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios')
            return (
                <View style={this.props.style}>
                    {iosPickerModal}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ modal: true })}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : normalize(40), width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : 0.68 * windowWidth(), borderWidth: 1, borderColor: color.blue, alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5 }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: fontSize.regular, marginRight: 30 }}> {this.state.type_absen}</Text>
                            <IconWrapper name='md-arrow-dropdown' type='ionicon' color={color.light_grey} size={20} onPress={() => this.setState({ modal: true })} style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 10 }} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View >);
        else
            return (
                <View style={this.props.style} >
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.type_absen}
                        style={{ height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : normalize(20), width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : normalize(150) }}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ type_absen: itemValue });
                            this.props.onSelect(itemValue, index);
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.props.items.map((item, key) => <Picker.Item label={item.description} value={item.id} key={key} />)}
                    </Picker>
                </View>);
    }
}

PickerWrapper.propTypes = {
    onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default PickerWrapper;
```

Comment: I'm using Picker from React Native. I've updated my post

Comment: It just shows the label from item.description, I'm trying to get the value from item.id

Comment: Edited once more

Comment: well it kinda of wokred :D but when i selected the item I got an error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc7a7ca6175f8b6b6'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: So does it keep crashing or did you figure it out?

Comment: I figured it out this error was coming in array. which is the array has integer value but we init in string charater

so that we need to convert the integer value into string

Comment: I have one more question, how do I show the "label" instead of the "value" in the picker, after the selection it shows the value